# Python "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Tags: python, multithreading, mysql-python

I am trying to implement multithreading in my python script that divides a list of dictionaries into multiple lists and updates the database by creating a separate database connection for each thread.

```
def updateResource(self, data, SELECT_QUERY, UPDATE_QUERY, CONTACTS_QUERY, CONTACT_ER_QUERY, INSERT_QUERY):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    self.select_query = SELECT_QUERY
    self.update_query = UPDATE_QUERY
    self.contacts_query = CONTACTS_QUERY
    self.contact_er_query = CONTACT_ER_QUERY
    self.insert_query = INSERT_QUERY

    for i in range(len(data)):
        self.arg1 = data[i]["system_name"]
        self.arg2 = data[i]["fdc_inv_sa_team"]
        try:
            query1_row = self.cursor.execute(self.select_query %(self.arg1))
            if query1_row:
                '''
                run update and insert queries
                commit
                '''
            else:
                ...
        except MySQLdb.Error as e:
            logger.error("Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1]))
        except Exception, e:
            logger.error("Error : ", str(e))
```

Running the thread -

```
def createThread(self, chunks, obj):
    for i in range(len(chunks)):
        cnx = MySQLdb.connect(host, user, passwd, db)
        cnx.autocommit(True)
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        new_thread = myThread(obj, cnx, cursor, chunks[i])
        new_thread.start()
        threads.append(new_thread)
    for new_thread in threads:
        new_thread.join()
```

Thread class -

```
class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, obj, conn, cur, data_to_deal):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.obj = obj
        self.conn = conn
        self.cur = cur
        self.data_to_deal = data_to_deal

    def run(self):
        self.obj.updateResource(self.data_to_deal, SELECT_QUERY, UPDATE_QUERY, CONTACTS_QUERY, CONTACT_ER_QUERY, INSERT_QUERY)
```

Implementing locks removes this error but makes the script slow as there are 16k dictionaries in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what did you asked about.
But generally the problem with connection solved by doing **workaround**:

1. disconnect (from master process)
2. fork
3. connect (both in master and in a worker)

It create N connections to DB, so you do not need lock for **querying** anymore.

And for many ORMs 3d step is optional cause ORM used to connect automatically when you do some query, [django do it as well](https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2012/01/06/django-reset-database-connection.html)
Disconnect logic is specific for ORM you use. [Django (not tested myself)](https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2012/01/06/django-reset-database-connection.html)

Of course there is optimized way: do reconnection logic only inside the worker.

And be aware, that DBs have connection limits, end every connection take some RAM.